# Keeping element in a fixed position until it intersects with another element, causing it to change to absolute positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have a product page where the description is a fixed element relative to the viewport. However, when scrolling all the way to the bottom, the element will overlap with the footer content and it doesn't look good.

What I'm trying to do is to use jQuery to determine the exact point where the bottom of the description element starts to overlap with the top of the footer element, and to change it to absolute position with a bottom equal to the position of the footer element. The result I want is so that it "sticks" to the top of the footer when it would otherwise overlap it.

Here's my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    //offset of bottom of element from top
    var osProduct = $('.product-single__meta').offset().top + $('.product-single__meta').height();
    //exact position where footer begins
    var osFooter = $('.return-link-wrapper').offset().top - 83;
    if(osProduct >= osFooter) {
      //change fixed positioning to be sticky to that exact pixel
      $('.product-single__meta').css('position','absolute');
      $('.product-single__meta').css('bottom', osFooter);
    }
    else {
      $('.product-single__meta').css('position','fixed');
      $('.product-single__meta').css('bottom','auto');
    }
});
```

*.product-single__meta* is the description div, and *.return-link-wrapper* is the footer div.

However, when I scroll past this overlapping point, the description div starts to really quickly switch between fixed and absolute positioning, rather than behaving how I want it to. Needless to say, the end result is not as expected. How can I achieve this behavior?

Comment: Do you have an example of the html?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is the code you're looking for set 100 to whatever you have where  your div element is distant exactly from top of the page. change rest to your needs. this is in jquery btw

```
(function ($) {
  $(document).ready(function(){

    // first we set the position to relative
    $('.product-single__meta').css('position','relative');

    // position absolute when user scrolls more than 100px
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            // set distance user needs to scroll before setting css
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
                $('.product-single__meta').css('position','absolute');
            } else {
                $('.product-single__meta').css('position','relative');
            }
        });


    });

});
  }(jQuery));
```